# Function returning a reference to an int can be assigned to an int

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I always thought that a signature like

```
int& val() {...}
```

would indicate to the caller, that a reference to an already existing int-value is returned. However, if I use that function and assign it to an `int` variable (not an `int&`), it compiles. The result is however a copy of the actual return value of the function - as shown by printing the addresses, like can be seen in the following session:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int v = 8;
int& vref()
{
    return v;
}

int main()
{
 /*declared type of x does not match the return type! However, no warnings/messages about any implicit conversion are given here*/
 int x = vref();  
 int& y = vref(); // correct type
 // Now I declare pointers to x,y and v and display their addresses
 int* ptr_x = &x;
 int* ptr_y = &y;
 int* ptr_v = &v;
 cout << "Addr of x: " << ptr_x << endl;
 cout << "Addr of y: " << ptr_y << endl;
 cout << "Addr of v: " << ptr_v << endl;
}
```

Resulting in `y` and `v` residing at the same memory location (which I would have expected) - but not `x`. So, I wonder, what is going on under the hood when assigning `int x = vref();`

Comment: Since `vref` returns a reference to `v`, `int x = vref();` is equivalent to `int x = v;` and `int& y = vref();`
  is equivalent to `int& y = v;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
int x = vref();
```

you make a *copy* of the original value, and store it into the unique and distinct variable `x`.

On the other hand, with:

```
int& y = vref();
```

you get a reference to the original `v` variable. The variable `y` can be seen as an *alias* of `v`. Any time you use `y` you're actually using `v`.

Because the `vref()` function returns an *alias* of `v`, the definition and initialization of `x` is really equivalent to:

```
int x = v;
```

Both `x` and `v` are the same types, so no type conversion is made.

This equivalence is of course the same for `y` which is equivalent to:

```
int& y = v;
```

---

Please note that the first "issue", making a copy of the returned value, is the reason why it's really no use to return a constant value.

Even a reference to constant (i.e. `int const&`) can still get its value copied.

The difference is that if you modify the copy (like the variable `x` in your example) you only modify the copy itself, not the original value.

So e.g. `x++` will increase the value of `x` but leave `v` unmodified. But `y++` will increase the value of `v`.

Comment: I understand that part - but what I don't understand why this isn't a case of an implicit type conversion. So my basic question is: Are int and int& different types. If so, I don't understand why the line "int x = vref()" is not a prime example of an implicit type-conversion

Comment: @P.Jo Yes, `int` and "reference to `int`" are two different and distinct types. *But* there's no conversion because `vref` doesn't return a value, it returns a reference, This reference is an alias of `v`. So `int x = vref();` is really exactly the same as `int x = v;`.

Comment: This is puzzling. I don't want to be pedantic, but what is wrong about the following reasoning: vref() returns int& therefore in an assignment like int x = vref(), we have on the left hand side a value of type int, whereas on the right hand is a value of type int&? If so, we have two distinct types on both sides.

Comment: @P.Jo even if there would be a type conversion it does not change that `x` is an `int` not a reference. What would this type conversion do? I mean, other than using the value of `v` to initialize `x`? Btw I am not a language lawyer and I don't want to be in your way of understanding the very details, just trying to understand what you are missing

Comment: @P.Jo Evaluating a lvalue reference is an lvalue expression producing the value of the referred object. For the purpose of initializing `x`, evaluting a reference to `int` is indistinguishable from using the identifier of an actual `int`.

Comment: @P.Jo `int x` declares an object `x` or type `int`. This unconditionally means an entirely distinct `int` object from any other `int` object that exists anywhere in your program, with its own address and its own unique address which will be different from any other `int`. This is true regardless of how the `int` object is actually initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess my main point was that it is somewhat error prone: Suppose I accidently forget the reference, i.e. I use "int x" in the declaration. Now, I look at the function signature and act as if I have a reference to an already existing value, but I am actually doing work on a copy of it. Too me, it seems a little bit error-prone.

Comment: @P.Jo That's an issue with design IMO. You could use static analyzers and code-reviews to help you catch such issues, But it doesn't stop that it's still valid, and that sometimes making a copy is actually what's intended.

Answer (score 1):

`vref` returns a reference to `v`. References cannot be rebound. The reference returned from `vref` will always refer to `v`. Using the reference to initialize another reference makes that other reference refer to `v`.

This however,

```
int x = vref();
```

makes a copy of `v` to initialize `x`. `x` is not a reference. `x` and `v` are two distinct integers.

> However, if I use that function and assign it to an int variable (not an int&), it compiles. The result is however a copy of the actual return value of the function - as shown by printing the addresses, like can be seen in the following session:

Totally correct.

There is no contradiction to `vref` returning a reference.